# Can't open Pyinstaller's output file

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, tkinter, pyinstaller

### SOLUTION:

The main issue was occurring due to `ImageTk` , this can be skipped by loading image using tkinter instead of PIL.ImageTk by using this command and using this object as normal you would do with PIL.ImageTk.

```
my_image = PhotoImage(file ="Image location here")
```

### MAIN ISSUE:

I'm trying to pack these files into a single executable file using pyinstaller, but after compilation, the executable file doesn't run, don't know where the error is, files in the given link, and installation log in pictures

### Command Used:

```
pyinstaller --onefile ui.py
```

Where ui.py is my driver script

### Files:

https://github.com/RoyalEagle73/NIT-JSR-Result-Leecher/tree/master/GUI%20%2B%20Source%20v2.0/Source

### Build Log( Images ):

[image]

[image]

### What I've already tried

tried Cx_Freeze as an alternative but no application seems to open the output file.

### here is what I'm importing overall in the whole program

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import fb
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import webbrowser
from tkinter import messagebox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
```

Comment: Your first link below "Files:" is wrong. Please show the output **as text in the question** formatted as a code block instead of linking screenshots.

Comment: What exactly means "the executable file doesn't run"? How exactly do you start the application? Do you get an error message? Does the program exit without any output?

Comment: https://github.com/RoyalEagle73/NIT-JSR-Result-Leecher/tree/master/GUI%20%2B%20Source%20v2.0/Source

Comment: Can't edit my question now, fresh user so forgive for ghe mistakes 

Comment: I normally run the executable file with double click and "right click and run " both, it never starts

Comment: Below your question you should see gray links like `share edit close delete flag`. Click on `edit` there or on this [edit] to edit your question. Try to run your program from a shell window and tell in your question what exactly happens. If you get an error message, copy & paste the message to your question

Comment: Ok, i'll make sure to do this next time, by now updated my questions

Comment: Run your program from a shell window, show the exact command in your question. Describe what happens. If you get any text output copy&paste it to the question. Show the output of `echo $?` after running your program.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "ui.py", line 1, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'

[4633] Failed to execute script ui`

Comment: Got this error, if not clear see the update section in question

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to access the github link in your question, I think it did not get  pasted properly. So I am unable to access your source files.

Try one of these:

```
 pyinstaller --onefile --noupx ui.py
```

or

```
pyinstaller --debug --onefile --noupx ui.py
```

The pyinstaller uses UPX. The [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html#using-upx) for pyinstaller states the following:

> PyInstaller looks for UPX on the execution path or the path specified
>   with the --upx-dir option. If UPX exists, PyInstaller applies it to
>   the final executable, unless the --noupx option was given. UPX has
>   been used with PyInstaller output often, usually with no problems.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Post updated, with the link, I'll try this one asap, first command does not work as I've tried after watching other answer, not sure about second one, will let you know in few moments

Comment: No but it never created issue before, using class and methods in script.py and using those methods in main script i.e. ui.py